# .net DataAnnotation and Globalization issue (server side)

Tags: .net, data-annotations, globalization, server-side

North America's format for dates is MM/dd/yyyy

I am working on project (asp.net MVC 2) for Australia where date format is d/MM/yyyy

in web.config I have

```
        <globalization
        fileEncoding="utf-8"
        requestEncoding="utf-8"
        responseEncoding="utf-8"
        culture="en-AU"
        uiCulture="en-AU"
        enableClientBasedCulture="true"
    />
```

in views .net renders dates in right format - "en-AU", but when I submit form with 14/11/2011 date my ModelState.IsValid equals to False.

How to teach dataannoation to properly validate dates in "en-AU" format?

//update

just found that issue related to GET only

```
using(Html.BeginForm("Search", "form", FormMethod.Post)) //Works
using(Html.BeginForm("Search", "form", FormMethod.Get)) //Does'n work
```

**Looks like it is a .net bug !!!

I tried on new mvc2/3 projects

when I use GET, mvc binding doesn't use current culture**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've got solution thank you for tens of different blog posts and articles.  Work perfectly, plus you can apply it not just for dates.

```
//Global.asax.cs
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ModelBinders.Binders[typeof (DateTime)] = new ForceCultureModelBinder<DateTime>();
    ModelBinders.Binders[typeof(DateTime?)] = new ForceCultureModelBinder<DateTime>();
}
```

and class

```
public class ForceCultureModelBinder<T> : IModelBinder where T : struct
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("bindingContext");

        T? valueAttempt = GetA(bindingContext);
        return valueAttempt == null ? (object) null : valueAttempt.Value;
    }

    private T? GetA(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        ValueProviderResult valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        if (valueResult == null)
            return null;

        T? result;
        try
        {
            result = (T?) valueResult.ConvertTo(typeof (T), Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(
                    bindingContext.ModelName, 
                    ex.InnerException.Message);
            return null;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: your exemple is useful for converting parameter entered values, using the user locale. I used it in one of my applications. I just added a single line of code in the catch in order to have an error message. Regards

Answer (score 6):

This behavior is by design. When you do a GET request, it puts the date in the URL. ASP.NET MVC makes the assumption that dates in the URL are invariant culture.

Why?

Well suppose I create the following URL: /posts/01-11-2011/ and send that to you. What does that mean to you?

Well it means show me the posts on January 11, 2011, because that works for my culture. But your culture probably denotes it as November 01, 2011. URLs should *uniquely* identify a resource. The same URL should not have different meanings depending on who is looking at it.

So we decided that our model binders would not convert values from the URL to the current culture, but *would* convert values from a form post. That made sense to us because a form post cannot be sent around and generally represents a user's input.

Comment: thank you, it explains the situation. and i agree with you if it a part of the PATH but in my case url is /posts?...&date=01-11-2011

for a get param I think culture has to work. And in mu case it has to be GET.
I already spend 2 days to find how to teach mvc to properly parse data.  No results yet :(

can you please show me some the sample?

Answer (score 0):

Hanselman has a good post on how to handle this client-side, where he does something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        //Ask ASP.NET what culture we prefer
        $.getJSON('/locale/currentculture', function (data) {
            //Tell jQuery to figure it out also on the client side.
            $.global.preferCulture(data);
        });
    });
```

source: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx

I do believe that the plugin is now called globalize (found [here](https://github.com/jquery/globalize)) but the API should be similar, if not the exact same.

Comment: my problem is on server side.  code renders everything properly on view level (I'm not touching browser side for now) but on server side after form submission (SUBMITTING SAME VALUE) data annotation engine expect data in en-US